# Can I use custom encoding to edit files over FTP in the Eclipse Text Editor

Tags: eclipse, encoding, utf-8, ftp, text-editor

I like to use UTF8 in my projects. It is my default encoding in Eclipse.
But sometimes I need to direct edit some files over FTP.

Is it possible to use Eclipse as remote text file editor of files in non-UTF8 encoding (in general, I need these: koi8r/u, cp1251, cp866)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Aptana Studio 3 (standalone or as a plugin) or RSE plugin for direct edits over FTP.
To view a file in different encoding use menu Edit/Set Encoding when the file is opened. Same applies to opening local files in non-default encoding.

Cheers,
Max